# Преобразовать строку в массив по разделителю

Tags: c++, arduino

Всем привет!
Функция принимает строку символов вида 10;Маша;Звезда-54, длина не определена заранее. Можно использовать строковые функции: strcmp, strcpy, strlen и т.д. и использовать нужно char*.

Как из такой строки создать массив (в роли разделителя ";")?

- arr[0] == 10
- arr[1] == Маша
- arr[2] == Звезда-54

Comment: Принципиально чтобы на arduino работало?

Comment: Нельзя использовать strtok для const char* поскольку strtok изменяет оригинальную строку. arr[2] способен вместить только 2 символа - Вам требуется массив для 3х char* или массив для 3х Си-строк char arr[3][MAX_LEN] или динамический массив Си-строк, который будет расти по мере нахождения новых подстрок.

Comment: Я принимаю пакет по UART 24;2;...10; (количество чисел - 27) и мне нужно из них сформировать массив.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, у вас есть `char str [] = {"10;20;30\0"}; ` и `int arr[3];`, и вы хотите сделать что-то вроде `split(str, arr);`?

Comment: Я хочу из строки вытянуть числа и из них собрать массив. Например строка {"Маша";"Витя";"Оля"}, а получить массив с такими значениями внутри name[0] == "Маша", name[1] == "Витя", name[2] == "Оля"

Comment: Вы меня окончательно запутали. Вам нужно порезать строку на подстроки или все же речь о числах? Как я помню из школьной программы, `"Маша"` это не число.

Comment: Приведите пример входной строки и того что должно быть на выходе

Comment: Наверное это называется строковый литерал правильно. Пример с именами самое то, не важно что в строке, цифры или буквы, главное разбить по ";" и куски положить по порядку в массив.

Comment: Так что, поможет кто-нибудь?

Comment: А в чем проблема? Заводите массив указателей достаточного размера. Проходите по строке и ищите разделители. Заносите в этот массив начало каждого найденного "слова", а вместо разделителя пишете 0. В принципе, можно и `strtok` (или `strtok_r`) использовать (если они на ардуино есть)

Comment: Мне бы пример, я в С++ не силен на таком уровне.